# Android gridview like in flickr

Tags: android, image, android-gridview

Hi im interested in achieving effect like in this screenshot

[image]

Question is how to add images to gridview with not discarding the aspect ratio and cropping it but adding them side by side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think StaggeredGridView is what best suited for your requirement.

this is the link go and download and attach this library to your project.

https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

I used this and it works very beautifully..!

Comment: can we have multiple number of columns in a single StaggeredGridView? Like 1 column in the first row 3 in second row and 2 in 3rd?

Comment: I dont think so.. You got to customize or may be have to use Linearlayout for that stuff